# Ember JS - routing from resourse to route

Tags: ember.js, routes

i'm trying to update and ember project from version 2.x to version 3.x, and one of my first issue is that in the route file i get this.resouce is not defined. i belive this was deprecated. the code looks like this :

```
  this.route('objects', function () {
    this.route('search', { path: '/' }, function () {
      this.resource('objects.items', { path: '/:search_id' }, function () {
        this.resource('objects.item', { path: '/item/:item_id'}, function () {
          this.route('general', { path: '/' });
          this.route('tab', { path: '/tab/:tab' });
          this.route('relations');
          this.route('diagram');
          this.route('comments');
          this.route('sources');
          this.route('views');
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

i've tried to simply change the resource to route and give resetNameSpace: true attribute, but didn't help. also i've tried various combinations, but without luck.
anyone with experience can help me redo this routing to be compatible with the latest ember?

Comment: what do you mean with "but without luck"? What didn't work?

Comment: example i've used this:
 `this.route('objects', function () {
    this.route('search', { path: '/' });
    this.route('items', { path: '/:search_id', resetNameSpace: true  }); 
    this.route('item', { path: '/item/:item_id' }, function () {
        this.route('general', { path: '/' });
        this.route('tab', { path: '/tab/:tab' });
        this.route('relations');
        this.route('diagram');
        this.route('comments');
        this.route('sources');
        this.route('views');
    });
  });` ,

Comment: but then i get " You attempted to define a `{{link-to "objects.item"}}` but did not pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments. More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: objects.item.general", 
at transitionToRoute("objects.item.general", id)

Comment: consider migrate to absolute route paths. so `{{link-to 'objects.search.items'}}` for example, and replace your `objects.items` resource with an `items` route.

Comment: thanks! i will try it

Comment: at my initial example the `this.resource('objects.items', { path: '/:search_id' }, function () {` is an optional segment. is a way to achive this without the resource? and still have the nested routes there?

Comment: @Lux - what do you think? is it possibel to have an optional segment? i want to avoid having the same models and code at 2 different places

Answer (score 1):

As `this.resource()` is actually an old Ember way of resetting the namespace, the `resetNameSpace: true` attribute does indeed do the same!

Because you used `this.resource('objects.items')`, you actually created a resetted namespace where `objects` was the route.

So your new router would look something like¹:

```
this.route('objects', function () {
    this.route('search', { path: '/'});
    this.route('items', { path: '/:search_id'});
    this.route('item', { path: '/item/:item_id' }, function () {
        this.route('general', { path: '/' });
        this.route('tab', { path: '/tab/:tab' });
        this.route('relations');
        this.route('diagram');
        this.route('comments');
        this.route('sources');
        this.route('views');
    });
});
```

This way you could still use `transitionToRoute("objects.item.general", id)`.

---

¹ Notice no `resetNameSpace` flag is used!

Comment: yes, but the objects.items.item.comments should also be a valid route. but finally managed to work it out with the resetNameSpace flag. thanks!